# Trim all whitespace from within html tags with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, smarty

it seems I have a very special problem as I couldn't find any related solution on the web so far. I have Smarty templates and I can pretty much remove all unnecessary whitespace with the trimwhitespace filter after making some slight modifications. However I cannot get rid of leading whitespace within tags. Please have a look at the following two examples:

```
<h1>A headline without any leading whitespace</h1>

<h1>
  A headline like it would be formatted by an IDE
</h1>
```

My problem is that the Smarty trimwhitespace output filter does not trim the second example. When I place an icon before the headline using CSS :before, there is whitespace between the icon and the second example but not when applied to the first example.

Is it possible to use preg_replace to trim the second example so that it looks the same in HTML as the first example does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?<=<h1>)\s*|\s*(?=<\/h1>)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/61

Comment: Thanks that nearly did the job. But I do not only need to replace between h1 tags but between all html tags. A slight modification of your regex works like a charme: (?<=>)\s*|\s*(?=<\/)

Comment: @MartinFriedrichBauer thanx..That should be easy ...making it generic :)

Comment: Good idea, what about using a `+` quantifier instead of `*`

Answer (score 0):

This function should help.

```
function anyname($string)
{
return preg_replace(array('/\s{2,}/', '/\n/'), '', $string);
}
```